# Puma: Having issue with iptables port 3000

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debian, iptables, puma

I'm having issue with iptables and puma(port 3000) using this config:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 18 packets, 1982 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   14  1076 ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh state NEW,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     *.*.*.*              anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     *.*.*.*              anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     *.*.*.*              anywhere            
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     *.*.*.*              anywhere            
   13  6666 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     *.*.*.*              anywhere             tcp dpt:3000 state NEW,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 31 packets, 2646 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

When I try to access port 3000 from authorize ip, no data is being return. But when I check using nmap if port 3000 is open. Did I misconfigured something in iptables? Thanks.

Comment: Just want to know if this is a development configuration and how you start your rails server (which command) ?

Comment: Can you post the output of `netstat -anpt` and `iptables-save`?

Comment: netstat -anpt
`https://gist.github.com/itsmechlark/4ef6aa0eefc8feac83db`

Comment: iptables-save 
`https://gist.github.com/itsmechlark/6c81de14fd99fb17d2ea`

Comment: BTW, puma is running as non-root user via monit.